# OCaml Menhir: Grammar is not working

Tags: parsing, ocaml, menhir

I am using menhir to define the Tiger language described in Modern Compiler Implementation in ML, [here](http://cs.nyu.edu/courses/fall13/CSCI-GA.2130-001/tiger-spec.pdf) is the manual:

```
exp:
  | lv = lvalue     { Lvalue lv }
  | i = INT         { Int i  }
  | s = STRING      { String s }
  ......


lvalue:
  | i = ID   { Id i }
  | lv = lvalue DOT i = ID
              { Field_exp (lv, i) }
  | lv = lvalue LBRACKET e = exp RBRACKET
              { Subscript (lv, e) }
```

However, this grammar does not recognize string like `a[3]` but it recognize `a.b`.

Then I add another rule to lvalue

```
  | i = ID LBRACKET e = exp RBRACKET
              { Subscript (Id i, e) }
```

Now my grammar recognize `a[3]` **but it does not recognize `a[r]`**

This seems so strange to me. Why can't `a[3]` be recognized by my original grammar, and why can't `a[r]` be recognized?

---

**Update**

Here is my grammar:

```
%{
open Lexing
open Ast
%}

%token <int> INT
%token <string> ID
%token <string> STRING
%token ARRAY BREAK DO ELSE END FOR
%token FUNCTION IF IN LET NIL OF
%token THEN TO TYPE VAR WHILE
%token LPAREN RPAREN LBRACE RBRACE
%token LBRACKET RBRACKET 
%token COLON SEMICOL COLONEQ
%token DOT COMMA 
%token PLUS MINUS TIMES DIVIDE
%token EQ NEQ GT GE
%token LT LE AMPERSAND PIPE
%token EOF

%nonassoc OF
%nonassoc DO
%nonassoc THEN
%nonassoc ELSE
%nonassoc COLONEQ
%left PIPE
%left AMPERSAND
%nonassoc EQ NEQ LT LE GT GE
%left PLUS MINUS
%left TIMES DIVIDE
%nonassoc UMINUS

%start <Ast.exp> prog

%%

prog:
  | e = exp EOF { e }
  ;


exp:
  | NIL             { Nil  }
  | BREAK           { Break }
  | i = INT         { Int i  }
  | s = STRING      { String s }
  | lv = lvalue     { Lvalue lv }
  | LPAREN es = exp_seq RPAREN 
                    { match es with
                      | [e] -> e
                      | es  -> Exp_seq es
                    }
  | MINUS e = exp %prec UMINUS 
                    { Negation_exp e }

  | i = ID LPAREN es = exp_list RPAREN                (* function call  *)
                    { Call_exp (i, es) }

  | i = ID LBRACE fc = field_create_list RBRACE 
                    { Rec_create (i, fc) }
  | i = ID LBRACKET e1 = exp RBRACKET OF e2 = exp 
                    { Arr_create (i, e1, e2) }
  | lv = lvalue COLONEQ e = exp
                    { Assignment (lv, e) }
  | IF test = exp THEN then_exp = exp ELSE else_exp = exp
                    { Ifthenelse (test, then_exp, else_exp) }
  | IF test = exp THEN then_exp = exp 
                    { Ifthen (test, then_exp) }
  | WHILE e1 = exp DO e2 = exp 
                    { Whileexp (e1, e2) }
  | FOR i = ID COLONEQ e0 = exp TO e1 = exp DO e2 = exp 
                    { Forexp (i, e0, e1, e2) }
  | LET decls = decl_list IN es = exp_seq END
                    { Letexp (decls, es)}
  | ae = arith_exp  { ArithExp ae }
  | ce = cmp_exp    { CmpExp ce }
  | be = bool_exp   { BoolExp be }

lvalue:
  | i = ID   { Id i }
  | lv = lvalue DOT i = ID
              { Field_exp (lv, i) }
  | i = ID LBRACKET e = exp RBRACKET
              { Subscript (Id i, e) }
  | lv = lvalue LBRACKET e = exp RBRACKET
              { Subscript (lv, e) }


exp_seq:
  | es = separated_list(SEMICOL, exp) { es }

exp_list:
  | el = separated_list(COMMA, exp) { el }

field_create_list:
  | fc = separated_list(COMMA, field_create) { fc }

field_create:
  | i = ID EQ e = exp  { (i, e) }



decl_list:
  | dl = nonempty_list(decl) { dl }

decl:
  | TYPE i = ID EQ t = ty         { Type_decl  (i, t) }
  | VAR i = ID COLONEQ e = exp    { Var_decl (i, None, e) }
  | VAR i = ID COLON tid = ID COLONEQ e = exp
                                  { Var_decl (i, Some tid, e) }
  | FUNCTION i = ID LPAREN fd = field_decl_list RPAREN EQ e = exp
                                  { Func_decl (i, fd, None, e) }
  | FUNCTION i = ID LPAREN fd = field_decl_list RPAREN COLON tid = ID EQ e = exp
                                  { Func_decl (i, fd, Some tid, e)}

ty:
  | i = ID                        { Type_id i }
  | ARRAY OF tid = ID             { Array_ty tid }
  | LBRACE fd = field_decl_list RBRACE 
                                  { Rec_ty fd }

field_decl_list:
  | fl = separated_list(COMMA, field_decl)   { fl }

field_decl:
  | i = ID COLON tid = ID  { (i, tid) }


%inline arith_exp:
  | e1=exp PLUS  e2=exp  { Add(e1, e2) }
  | e1=exp MINUS e2=exp  { Sub(e1, e2) }
  | e1=exp TIMES e2=exp  { Mul(e1, e2) }
  | e1=exp DIVIDE e2=exp { Div(e1, e2) }

%inline cmp_exp:
  | e1=exp EQ  e2=exp { Eq(e1, e2) }
  | e1=exp NEQ e2=exp { Neq(e1, e2) }
  | e1=exp LT  e2=exp { Lt(e1, e2) }
  | e1=exp LE  e2=exp { Le(e1, e2) }
  | e1=exp GT  e2=exp { Gt(e1, e2) }
  | e1=exp GE  e2=exp { Ge(e1, e2) }

%inline bool_exp:
  | e1=exp AMPERSAND e2=exp { And(e1, e2) }
  | e1=exp PIPE e2=exp { Or(e1, e2) }
```

Lexer:

```
{
open Lexing
open Parser
exception SyntaxError of string

let next_line lexbuf =
  let pos = lexbuf.lex_curr_p in
  lexbuf.lex_curr_p <-
    { pos with pos_bol = lexbuf.lex_curr_pos;
    pos_lnum = pos.pos_lnum + 1
    }

}

let int = ['0' - '9'] ['0' - '9']*
let newline = '\n' | 'r' | "\r\n"
let whitespace = [' ' '\t']+
let id = ['a' - 'z' 'A' - 'Z' '_'] ['a' - 'z' 'A' - 'Z' '0' - '9' '_']*

rule read = parse
  | whitespace            { read lexbuf }
  | newline               { next_line lexbuf; read lexbuf }
  | '"'                   { read_string (Buffer.create 17) lexbuf }
  | "/*"                  { comment lexbuf; read lexbuf }
  | eof                   { EOF }
  | '('                   { LPAREN }
  | ')'                   { RPAREN }
  | '{'                   { LBRACE }
  | '}'                   { RBRACE }
  | '['                   { LBRACKET }
  | ']'                   { RBRACKET }
  | '+'                   { PLUS }
  | '-'                   { MINUS }
  | '*'                   { TIMES }
  | '/'                   { DIVIDE }
  | '='                   { EQ }
  | "<>"                  { NEQ }
  | "<"                   { LT }
  | "<="                  { LE }
  | '>'                   { GT }
  | ">="                  { GE }
  | '&'                   { AMPERSAND }
  | '|'                   { PIPE }
  | ":="                  { COLONEQ }
  | ';'                   { SEMICOL }
  | ':'                   { COLON }
  | '.'                   { DOT }
  | ','                   { COMMA }
  | "array"               { ARRAY }
  | "break"               { BREAK }
  | "do"                  { DO }
  | "else"                { ELSE }
  | "end"                 { END }
  | "for"                 { FOR }
  | "function"            { FUNCTION }
  | "if"                  { IF }
  | "in"                  { IN }
  | "let"                 { LET }
  | "nil"                 { NIL }
  | "of"                  { OF }
  | "then"                { THEN }
  | "to"                  { TO }
  | "type"                { TYPE }
  | "var"                 { VAR }
  | "while"               { WHILE }
  | int                   { INT (int_of_string (Lexing.lexeme lexbuf)) }
  | id                    { ID (Lexing.lexeme lexbuf) }

and read_string buf =
  parse
  | '"'                   { STRING (Buffer.contents buf) }
  | '\\' '/'              { Buffer.add_char buf '/'; read_string buf lexbuf }
  | '\\' '\\'             { Buffer.add_char buf '\\'; read_string buf lexbuf }
  | '\\' 'b'              { Buffer.add_char buf '\b'; read_string buf lexbuf }
  | '\\' 'f'              { Buffer.add_char buf '\012'; read_string buf lexbuf }
  | '\\' 'n'              { Buffer.add_char buf '\n'; read_string buf lexbuf }
  | '\\' 'r'              { Buffer.add_char buf '\r'; read_string buf lexbuf }
  | '\\' 't'              { Buffer.add_char buf '\t'; read_string buf lexbuf }
  | [^ '"' '\\']+         { Buffer.add_string buf (Lexing.lexeme lexbuf);
                            read_string buf lexbuf }
  | _                     { raise (SyntaxError ("Illegal string character: " ^ Lexing.lexeme lexbuf)) }
  | eof                   { raise (SyntaxError ("String is not terminated")) }

and comment = parse
  | "*/"                  { () }
  | "/*"                  { comment lexbuf; comment lexbuf }
  | _
```

and ast.ml

```
type exp = 
  | Nil             
  | Break           
  | Int             of int
  | String          of string 
  | Lvalue          of lvalue 
  | Exp_seq         of exp list 
  | Negation_exp     of exp
  | Call_exp        of id * exp list 
  | Arr_create      of type_id * exp * exp 
  | Rec_create      of type_id * field_create list
  | Assignment      of lvalue  * exp
  | Ifthenelse      of exp * exp * exp 
  | Ifthen          of exp * exp 
  | Whileexp        of exp * exp
  | Forexp          of id  * exp * exp * exp 
  | Letexp          of decl list * exp list
  | ArithExp        of arith_exp 
  | BoolExp         of bool_exp 
  | CmpExp          of cmp_exp 


and decl = 
  | Type_decl of type_id * ty
  | Func_decl of id * (field_decl list) * return_ty option * exp
  | Var_decl  of id * (type_id option)  * exp

and id              = string 
and type_id         = string 
and return_ty       = type_id 
and array_type      = type_id
and field_decl      = id * type_id
and field_create    = id * exp

and ty = 
  | Type_id  of type_id
  | Array_ty of array_type
  | Rec_ty   of field_decl list

and lvalue = 
  | Id        of id 
  | Subscript of lvalue * exp 
  | Field_exp of lvalue * id

and arith_exp =
  | Add of exp * exp
  | Sub of exp * exp
  | Mul of exp * exp
  | Div of exp * exp

and bool_exp =
  | Or of exp * exp
  | And of exp * exp

and cmp_exp =
  | Eq of exp * exp
  | Neq of exp * exp
  | Lt of exp * exp
  | Le of exp * exp
  | Gt of exp * exp
  | Ge of exp * exp
```

Comment: You need to post the whole grammar and the tokenizer, any answer will just be guesswork otherwise.

Comment: @Drup Hi, I updated the post

Comment: It turns out, in my lexer.mll, `newline` is set to 'r' instead of '\r'. So 'a[r]' is read as 'a[]'. Changing it back fix the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your grammar is not LL(1), as stated by menhir when you compile:

```
Warning: one state has shift/reduce conflicts.
Warning: one shift/reduce conflict was arbitrarily resolved.
```

You should always solve such issues. When you give the option `-d`, menhir will generate a `foo.conflicts` file that explains the conflict.

In this case, the issue comes from this line:

```
  | i = ID LBRACKET e1 = exp RBRACKET OF e2 = exp
```

It is not possible, with a lookup of 1, to distinguish between `a[r]` and `a[r] of e`. I would advise to change your syntax.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Are you suggesting to change the grammar? Cause the syntax is already defined in the book.

Comment: It is possible to transform your grammar to make it LL(1), but it's a bit annoying. Now you have an idea where too look, try by yourself first. You can also just change the syntax, no shame in that. :p